# How to get "BasicFunctions" from WolframLanguageData with implicit entity

Tags: core-language, symbols, entity

I am trying to get a list of the functions that have property `"FunctionalityAreas" -> "BasicFunctions"`.  The following does not work:

```
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
   {EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "FunctionalityAreas"] -> 
    ContainsAny[{"BasicFunctions"}]}] // EntityList
(*
Missing["QueryValueIncompatibleWithProperty", \
{"WolframLanguageSymbol", "FunctionalityAreas", 
  ContainsAny[{"BasicFunctions"}]}]
*)
```

However, `EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "FunctionalityAreas"]` is a valid property for `WolframLanguageData["Properties"]`. I've tried the both with and without wrapping in `EntityProperty` and with and without `ContainsAny`.

How do I collect these with an implicit entity filter on the `"FunctionalityAreas"`?

Comment: Not an implicit entity filter, but I'd still mention `WolframLanguageData[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "BasicFunctions"}]]`

Comment: `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "BasicFunctions"}]]` also works.

Answer (score 2):

This post is made to put answers given as comments on record as a formal answer.

[ilian]

```
EntityClass[
   "WolframLanguageSymbol", 
   {EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
    "FunctionalityAreas"] -> "BasicSymbols"}] // EntityList
```

or
[m_goldberg]

```
EntityClass[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "FunctionalityAreas" -> ContainsAll[{"BasicSymbols"}]] // EntityList
```